# I'm trying to send emails using ActiveAdmin but it's showing no route matches post error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have setup a simple email form but I dont know how to use ActiveAdmin to send emails when I click the 'send email' button, i did not find any helping documentation regarding email and mailer setup in Active Admin,

I had added these codes to development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin' }
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
host = '0.0.0.0.:3000/admin/'
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings =
{

      :address            => 'smtp.sendgrid.com',
      :port               => 587,
      :domain             => 'sendgrid.com',
      :authentication     => :login,
      :user_name          => 'xxxxx',
      :password           => 'xxxxxx',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

and these lines to emailer.rb in mailers:

```
def contact(to, subject, message, sent_at = Time.now)
       @subject = subject
       @recipients = to
       @from = 'no-reply@xxxx.com'
       @sent_on = sent_at
       @body["title"] = 'This is title'
       @body["email"] = 'sender@yourdomain.com'
       @body["message"] = message
       @headers = {}
end
```

I would like to know how to setup an email sending form using ActiveAdmin and how to use sendgrid or any other platform to send it briefly, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [Sendgrid](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby) maintain a gem for your need. Check it out.